# LOV working as expected in Select List, not in Display as text(LOV)

Tags: oracle-apex, lov

Working on an app in Oracle APEX, time entries are represented as floats in the DB, but I want to display them properly in the app iteself, so 15.5 displays as 15:30. For that, I created a Static LOV in Shared Components.

It works perfectly in Select List, but when I try to use the same LOV on the same entries in a report, istead of 15:30 it shows 1530.

Any idea what might be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

There are several places where you can enter date formats, but I think it would be most practical to make sure that you define your LOV is such a way that its display value is of type VARCHAR2. In that case, it will be displayed the same where ever you use it. For the return value you simply retain the DATE type.

For example:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'HH24:MI') display_value
,      SYSDATE return_value
FROM   DUAL
```